# How can i maintain Agora.io video call memory usage

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, video-streaming, out-of-memory, agora.io

Platform Unity 2019.4.8.f1
Apk tested on Android devices
Api lvl 21+

Test failure on some devices that have 2gb memory.
Our team has implemented a unity project and we use agora for video call. Our streaming configs are very low, 15fps, 65bit. But when we test the app on phones that have 2gb memory, some times later(about 5-10min) app crashes. We try to find out the problem and according to diagnostic tools agora uses lots of memory, We cannot find any limitation from agora sdk and cannot reduce memory usage, is there any idea about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, did you make sure if this is an Application level memory management issue? e.g., you created instance of renderers but did not release in time?

If it is SDK level issue, you probably won't find a solution from the public.  I suggest you to [create a ticket](https://agora-ticket.agora.io/) to ask the question directly to the Agora support team.  Please provide your quantified analysis and the crash log when you submit that.